# How does pygments guess lexer?

Tags: markdown, pygments

I'm using middleman-syntax to highlight code in my blog

I'm writing my templates in markdown... and was wondering, how does pygments guess lexer?

````
  if I write

  ´´´ruby
  ruby code here
  ```

  it doesnt work

  if I write

  ```      
  #!ruby
  ruby here
  ```

  it does

  If I write

  ```
  <?php
  php code here
  ```

  It does
````

Is there a list of how pygments guess it?

Comment: I don't know how pygments specifically does it, but you can build up some bigrams and trigrams of token probabilities, parse out the code into these tokens, and compare the distribution to your known/classified code fragments and make a pretty accurate guess based on that.

Comment: i'd like to know what i can use and what not in my templates

Comment: you mean what languages? http://pygments.org/languages/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Pygments does not guess.

[**Linguist does**](http://github.com/github/linguist).

Comment: No, you are wrong. See this: https://github.com/dagwieers/pygments/blob/d4425131d42a69651d27260e45bdfd68f29f06ad/pygments/lexers/__init__.py#L288. It basically iterates through all languages, analyzing and returning the best match.